# sql data source re binding question

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, oracle, gridview

In my gridview after an insert operation has been done I am filtering the sqldatasource by ID. I am getting an error that the item drop down box selected value is not in the list. To test my theory I created a new sql data source with only the select statement and after the insert operation I am binding it to my grid view and filtering by Id and I get my result.

The question Having a second data source is not the solution so is it possible that there is some way to use sqldatasource1? what I tried is sqldatasource.databind() and gridview.databind() on the inserted and inserting metheds in many test cases but still that doesnt work.

I dont have any filters applied on the original data source?

Comment: This will be a lot easier to answer if you post up your code, or at least the relevant parts of it.

Comment: Please post your sample code to get answer.

Comment: As above posting code would be most helpful, but you could if you haven't already watch events and set up a method to populate your dropdown and other controls after postback, so that you can assess what controls should be populated with what data. For example if a user is selecting a row in a GridView, perhaps the dropdown's selection should correspond to a value in that row; in that case you could set the value for the dropdown as part of the GridView RowDataBound event.

Comment: See the following links: http://www.waronerrors.com/kb/bind-an-aspnet-textbox-to-an-sqldatasource-programmatically.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Code is better but if you're loading your datasource from code then you would try something like this after it inserts or does whatever it needs to:

```
gridview.datasource = [class or function that returns datasource];
gridview.databind();
```

and that should repopulate your data.

Comment: same with dropdownlists, reload the datasource then databind again.